# How to install Qmmp plugin for YouTube?

Tags: plugin, youtube, qmmp

I see there is a [Youtube plugin for Qmmp](https://github.com/rigon/qmmp-plugin-youtube) *"to search and play musics directly from YouTube "*.

How should it be installed?

---

It is not a part of the Qmmp Plugin Pack (`qmmp-plugin-pack`).

Comment: You could also ask by creating [a github issue](https://github.com/rigon/qmmp-plugin-youtube/issues).

Answer (score 0):

The [Youtube plugin for Qmmp](https://github.com/rigon/qmmp-plugin-youtube) project was updated. There, you can find all information about how to install the plugin.

If you are an ArchLinux user, you can install it directly from AUR with:

```
yaourt qmmp-plugin-youtube
```